# Looking for VB6 Report XP file

Tags: vb6

Please i would want to know what kind of VB6 file that generates a report, in a VB programming?

Comment: Perhaps you could be more informative in your question. Are you talking about something like Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an 3rd party reporting tool then i would strongly recommend Active Reports (from datadynamics). I used it in my last job, and preferred it over Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0):

VB6 had a basic version (should work for most needs) of the crystal reports engine in it.  That is how you created reports with VB6 without 3rd party tools or creating your own.

EDIT:

Here's some links on how to use it:

http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/using-crystal-reports-vb6-tutorial
http://www.vbexplorer.com/VBExplorer/vb_feature/august2000/using_crystal_reports.asp

Comment: you sure vb6 come with CR? I don't remember seeing it but last time i used VB6 it's like 4 years ago... I know VB.Net do have a basic version of CR

Comment: Yes, I does.  I used VB6 extensively and Crystal in it. :)

Comment: I meant to say yes, it does. :)

Comment: Wasn't it just the higher version of VB6 that provided this, like VB6 Pro?

Comment: That's a good question.  I don't remember on that one.  I only used VB6 Pro so you might have something there.